# custom query string parser returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript

I built a utility function. You pass it an array of values and it checks if all of those values are keys in the query string. If all the values are keys in the query string, it returns true, otherwise false.

Here is the function:

```
function hasParams(haystack, needle){
  var keys = [];
  var needles = $.isArray( needle ) ? needle : [needle];
  var needles_len = needles.length;
  var found = 0;

  if(!haystack.indexOf('?') > 0){
      return false;
  }

  var query = haystack.substr(haystack.indexOf('?') + 1).split("&");
  for(var i=0;i<query.length;i++){
    var key = query[i].split("=")[0];
    keys.push(key);
  }

  for(var j=0;i<keys.length;j++){
    for(var k=0;i<needles.length;k++){
      if(keys[j] == needles[k]){
        found++;
      }
      if(needles_len == found){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

This should return true (since the query string contains both status_filter_is and user_filter_is), but it returns false:

```
hasParams("/contacts/56f33c236d616354c0020000/tasks?contactable_type=Lead&id=56f33c236d616354c0020000&status_filter_is=unresolved&user_filter_is=all&action=index&controller=tasks&contact_id=56f33c236d616354c0020000&sort=date_due&direction=asc&page=", ['status_filter_is', 'user_filter_is'])
```

Comment: is `hasParams("?foo=bar")` a valid querystring? if so, `if(!haystack.indexOf('?') > 0){` will not work as intended. I'd recommend just `if(haystack.indexOf('?') === -1){`

Comment: Also note that duplicate keys are going to give you strange behavior; `?foo=bar&foo=baz', for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `for` loops have `i` in the middle instead of `j` or `k`.

Comment: Silly mistake. Thanks for finding it. I will mark correct when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `i<keys.length;` should be `j<keys.length;`

Secondly `i<needles.length;` should be `k<needles.length;`